# In how many ways can $20$ indistinguishable pencils be distributed among four children $A$,$B$,$C$ and $D$?

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can $20$ indistinguishable pencils be distributed among four children $A$,$B$,$C$ and $D$?

What is the actual technique for solving such problems?Please help me.

Comment: 1. Are you allowed to give zero pencils to some people ? 2. Have you heard of "stars and bars" combinatorics ?

Comment: No,I am a new to this subject and like to solve challenging questions of combinatorics.So,please enrich me with your thoughts.It will perhaps help me for more clear conception.

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay. I don't see an answer to question (1).

Comment: Yes for (1).Do you have any other queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

What is the number of ways to write $20$ as an ordered sum of $4$ non-negative integers?

Comment: It should be 23C3 ways.Isn't it?

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay.: Indeed it is.

Answer (score 0):

If a person can receive $0$ pencils(distinguishable)..

$1^{st}$ pencil can go to any of the $4$ persons, $2^{nd}$ pencil can go to any of the $4$ persons, .... similarly the $20^{th}$ pencil can go to any of the $4$ persons. So total number if ways = $4\times 4\times\cdots \times 4=4^{20}$

If a person has to receive at least $1$ pencil..

Choose any 4 pencils to be given initially to the 4 persons in ${20\choose 4}\times 4!$ ways. Remains 16 pencils. Now similar to the previous case:$1^{st}$ pencil can go to any of the $4$ persons, $2^{nd}$ pencil can go to any of the $4$ persons, $\cdots$$16^{th}$ pencil can go to any of the $4$ persons.o total number of ways ${20\choose 4}\times 4!\times4^{16}$

If pencils are indistinguishable

If a person can receive $0$ pencils the standard formula $$\text{pencils}+\text{number of persons}-1\choose \text{number of persons}-1$$
And $4!$ to be multiplied since the persons are distinguishable.

So $${20+4-1\choose 4-1}4!={23\choose 3}4!$$

And if each person is to receive at least $1$ pencil, then give each a pencil beforehand and distribute the remaining pencils in the above method i.e.$${16+4-1\choose4-1}4!={19\choose 3}4!$$

Comment: It has been clearly stated that the pencils are *indistinguishable*

Comment: What you have stated is for distinguishable particles.Isn't it?

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay. Edited to suit your needs..